# How to exclude certain file types with PHP readdir?

Tags: php

I am using a php scan directory script that will scan the contents of a directory and then populate the page with links to the directory contents.

```
<?php
$count = 0;
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {$count++;
        print("<a href=\"".$file."\">".$file."</a><br />\n");
    }
}
echo '<br /><br /><a href="..">Return</a>';
closedir($handle);
}
?
```

I am wondering how I can exclude certain files or file types like test.xml, durka.xslt or .html from showing up on the populated page. I have some code but not sure how to integrate it. Any help would be very appreciated...

```
?php
if ($handle = opendir(‘.’)) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
{
if ($file != “.” && $file != “..”
&& $file != “NOT-TO-BE-IN-1.php”
&& $file != “NOT-TO-BE-IN-2.html”
&& $file != “NOT-TO-BE-IN-3.jpg”
&& $file != “”
&& $file != “”
&& $file != “”
&& $file != “”
&& $file != “”

)
```

Comment: Make sure you replace those magic quotes `‘’  “ ”` with standard ascii ones `''  ""`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php

  // These files will be ignored
  $excludedFiles = array (
    'excludeMe.file',
    'excludeMeAs.well'
  );

  // These file extensions will be ignored
  $excludedExtensions = array (
    'html',
    'htm',
    'php'
  );

  // Make sure we ignore . and ..
  $excludedFiles = array_merge($excludedFiles,array('.','..')); 

  // Convert to lower case so we are not case-sensitive
  for ($i = 0; isset($excludedFiles[$i]); $i++) $excludedFiles[$i] = strtolower(ltrim($excludedFiles[$i],'.'));
  for ($i = 0; isset($excludedExtensions[$i]); $i++) $excludedExtensions[$i] = strtolower($excludedExtensions[$i]);

  // Loop through directory
  $count = 0;
  if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
      $extn = explode('.',$file);
      $extn = array_pop($extn);
      // Only echo links for files that don't match our rules
      if (!in_array(strtolower($file),$excludedFiles) && !in_array(strtolower($extn),$excludedExtensions)) {
        $count++;
        print("<a href=\"".$file."\">".$file."</a><br />\n");
      }
    }
    echo '<br /><br /><a href="..">Return</a>';
    closedir($handle);
  }

?>
```

Comment: This seems to work great but it puts a link with a dot on first line then a link with 2 dots on second line. I am not too sure how to get rid of those

Comment: If it may help someone, i just used that piece of code and fixed it :
you either have to remove the "ltrim" call which removes the first dots from the string and makes the "." and ".." strings empty, or place the array_merge AFTER the two for loops.

Comment: hello.. it works! could you please help me how to sort the result in alphabetically order or latest modified file? thx

Answer (score 2):

Other way:

```
$excludeExtensions = array(
    'php',
    'html',
    'jpg'
);

if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && !in_array(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $excludeExtensions))
```

EDIT: again I was too late:)

Answer (score 1):

you can also just use `glob`:

```
foreach (glob("*.{php|html|jpg}",GLOB_BRACE) as $file) {
    echo file_get_contents($file);
}
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php for more info

Comment: That's not what he wants (he wants to exclude stuff). Besides, it's not even valid `glob` usage. You'd have to do: `glob("*.{php,html,jpg}", GLOB_BRACE)`

Comment: sorry, my bad. I update the answer. I think i't easier to include the stuff he wants than exclude all the files he doesn't want...

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$count = 0;
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != ".." 
    && $file != "NOT-TO-BE-IN-1.php"
    && $file != "NOT-TO-BE-IN-2.html"
    && $file != "NOT-TO-BE-IN-3.jpg"
    && substr($file,-strlen(".html")) != ".html" //if you don't want to include .html files, for instance
    && substr($file,-strlen(".js")) != ".js" //if you don't want to include .js files, for instance
    && $file != ""
    ) {$count++;
        print("<a href=\"".$file."\">".$file."</a><br />\n");
    }
}
echo '<br /><br /><a href="..">Return</a>';
closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
{
if ($file != "." && $file != ".."
&& $file != "NOT-TO-BE-IN-1.php"
&& $file != "NOT-TO-BE-IN-2.html"
&& $file != "NOT-TO-BE-IN-3.jpg"
&& $file != ""
&& $file != ""
&& $file != ""
&& $file != ""
&& $file != ""
)
    echo file_get_contents($file);
```

will show contents of all pages which haven't name

- NOT-TO-BE-IN-1.php
- NOT-TO-BE-IN-2.html
- NOT-TO-BE-IN-3.jpg

you can restrict certain filepath with

```
if (!preg_match('/(php|html|jpg)/', $file))
```

Comment: You need to replace those magic quotes `‘’  “ ”` with standard ascii ones `''  ""`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$excluded_files = array('test.xslt');
$excluded_ext   = array('html');

while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != ".." &&
        !in_array($file, $excluded_files) &&
        !in_array(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $excluded_ext)) 
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```